# Htaccess for avoiding index.php?page= from URL

Tags: .htaccess

My project has URLs like http://domain.com/index.php?page=home/contactus , http://domain.com/index.php?page=events/announcementdetails/80 etc.

I want to avoid the **index.php?page=** and the parameters like 80 in the given URL and want to change the URL to http://domain.com/home/contactus and http://domain.com/events/announcementdetails. How can I achieve this using htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```