# htaccess url rewrite index.php?page=pagename

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'd like to use `htaccess` to alter my URL for a website I'm working on..

- URL currently: `domain.com/index.php?page=pagename`
- I want it to be: `domain.com/pagename`

Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?page=$0 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you Shiva, it worked, however it doesn't display the content as it should now. It changes the url correctly but the page is now not found. can you advise? @Shiva

Comment: Your welcome. Does it show the correct URL when you replace `[L]` by `[R,L]`?

Comment: There was an error in my answer, there is no leading slash. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, It works and show the correct URL.. however it doesnt show the page content anymore, says page not found. I'm not sure how best to word this.. 
When I click one of my menu buttons, it remains on the index.php page but changes the get variable and calls the appropriate content..
What its doing now is leaving the index page and going to whatever page we have just set it to e.g. /pagename

I essentially need to keep the URL as index.php?page=pagename, but hide the extensions and just show page name. I hope that made sense.

Comment: I'm thinking that you've take the problem the wrong side. Don't you need to do thing like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310860/htaccess-for-avoiding-index-phppage-from-url?

Comment: I think so too :/ It's too much for my designer brain.. I tried the solution you linked there but still not working.. I will figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the update Shiva, works perfectly now.. much appreciated